# Include order is relevant on scope but not on finder options

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

Depending on the order I place the includes in the scope, sequelize won't fetch one of the includes I requested. Oddly, if instead of a scope I put the options directly in the finder options (`findOne()` in this case), both requests work correctly. Why is this happening?

```js
    const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
    const sequelize = new Sequelize({ dialect: 'sqlite', storage: 'db.sqlite' });

    const Foo = sequelize.define('foo', { name: Sequelize.STRING });
    const Bar = sequelize.define('bar', { name: Sequelize.STRING });

    Foo.belongsToMany(Bar, { through: 'foo_bars', foreignKey: 'fooId' });
    Foo.belongsTo(Bar, { foreignKey: 'barId', as: 'whatever' });

    const includeOrder1 = { include: [{ model: Bar, as: 'whatever' }, Bar] };
    const includeOrder2 = { include: [Bar, { model: Bar, as: 'whatever' }] };

    Foo.addScope('test1', includeOrder1);
    Foo.addScope('test2', includeOrder2);

    const logGotWhatever = obj => console.log('Got whatever: ' + !!obj.whatever);

    sequelize.sync()
        .then(() => Bar.create({ name: 'The Bar' }).then(bar => {
            return Foo.create({ name: 'The Foo', barId: bar.id }).then(foo => foo.addBar(bar));
        }))
        .then(() => Foo.findOne(includeOrder1).then(logGotWhatever))
        .then(() => Foo.findOne(includeOrder2).then(logGotWhatever))
        .then(() => Foo.scope('test1').findOne().then(logGotWhatever))
        .then(() => Foo.scope('test2').findOne().then(logGotWhatever));
```

After running `npm install sequelize sqlite3`, the code above outputs:

```
Got whatever: true
Got whatever: true
Got whatever: false
Got whatever: true
```

Although I expected `true` in all four cases.

I'm using the most recent (non-beta) version of sequelize at the moment: 4.42.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed a bug, which was indirectly resolved by [PR #9735](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/pull/9735) in 2018-10-28, which changed how includes are dealt with (both in scopes and in finder options) and is available in v5.0.0-beta.14 and above.

Running the code above with `npm install sequelize@next sqlite3` yields:

```
Got whatever: true
Got whatever: true
Got whatever: true
Got whatever: true
```

As it should.

This fix probably will not be backported to v4 because it involved breaking changes on how includes work (although it isn't exactly a catastrophic change, is is technically a breaking change).